# way to have more than one prediction with classifier

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using scikit learn for document classification and i would like to know if there is a way to predict more than one classe (with the coresponding probability)

Here is the code i'm using :

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=4000, min_df=4, strip_accents="unicode", analyzer="word", max_features=4000,stop_words=stopwords, charset="utf-8", token_pattern="\w{4,}") 
x1_vect=vectorizer.fit_transform(x1)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
#or
#clf = MultinomialNB()

clf.fit(x1_vect,y1)
prediction = clf.predict(xpred_vect)
```

I get only on prediction and would like to have more (with corresponding probability)

Comment: You might be looking for the `predict_proba` method.

Answer (score 0):

In fact (I answered my own question), for some classifier (linearSVC that i used), there is a method called

```
clf.decision_function
```

which gives the "The confidence score for a sample that is the signed distance of that sample to the hyper plane"

Answer (score 0):

`linearSVC` has `.decision_function()` for that. Some other classifiers give predictions between 0 and 1 with `.predict_proba()`